# AZURE SQL DoCmd.RunSQL のエラー

Tags: sql, azure, ms-access, sql-azure

AZURE SQLでAccessの DoCmd.RunSQL "update TbaleA set AA='BB' where UNO=1"　を繰り返すと以下のエラーとなります。
解決策ご存知の方、サポートお願いします。

Watch : + : DBEngine.Errors(0) : "カレント レコードがありません。" : Object/Error : インポート

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]